# How to echo specific value from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to echo a specific value from an array using forach, everything seams working fine but the value gets looped.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=[.!?]| [.!?][\'"])\s+/ix';
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam. Quisque semper justo at risus. Donec venenatis, turpis vel hendrerit interdum, dui ligula ultricies purus, sed posuere libero dui id orci. Nam congue, pede vitae dapibus aliquet, elit magna vulputate arcu, vel tempus metus leo non est. Etiam sit amet lectus quis est congue mollis. Phasellus congue lacus eget neque. Phasellus ornare, ante vitae consectetuer consequat, purus sapien ultricies dolor, et mollis pede metus eget nisi. Praesent sodales velit quis augue. Cras suscipit, urna at aliquam rhoncus, urna quam viverra nisi, in interdum massa nibh nec erat.';
$sentences = preg_split($re, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($sentences as $key => $value)
{
  echo $sentences[3];
}
?>
```

**Output**:

Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus.

I need to echo $sentences[3] only one. Any ideas? Thank you all :)

Comment: Then why are you using a foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($sentences as $key => $value)
{
  echo $sentences[3];
}
```

Remove the foreach loop and type:

```
echo $sentences[3];
```

only.
The reason you do not need for-loop is because it will just loop through the `$sentence` array and echo `$sentences[3]` on each round.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `$sentences[3]` 12 times, because that's the length of the `$sentences` array, so remove the foreach if you just want to show the 3rd sentence